# Tree not functioning as exspected

Tags: python, tree, tic-tac-toe

I am trying to have my program load a tree of every possible tic-tac-toe board and then when given a random board input it can print out all the possible next moves based on the tree. However, when I try to do this all of my nodes seem to return `None`, except the root node.

My code right now:

```
import random

def main():        
    root = createNode(board, None, "X") 
    setBoard = (" ", " ", " ",
                " ", "X", "X",
                " ", " ", "O")

    nextMoves = find(root, setBoard)
    print(nextMoves)
    for child in nextMoves.children:
        printBoard(child.boardState)

boardCases = set()

board = [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]

def printBoard(board):
    for i in range(3):
        print(board[i*3], end="")
        print("|", end="")
        print(board[i*3+1], end="")
        print("|", end="")
        print(board[i*3+2], end="")
        print("")
        if i < 2:
            print("-+-+-")
    print("~~~~~~~~~~~~")


def checkForWin(board, c):

    # all column cases
    for i in range(3):
        if board[i] == c and board[i+3] == c and board[i+6] == c:
            #print(c + " wins!")
            return True

    #all row cases     
    for i in range(3):
        if board[i*3] == c and board[i*3+1] == c and board[i*3+2] == c:
            #print(c + " wins!")
            return True

    #all across cases
    if board[0] == c and board[4] == c and board[8] == c:
        #print(c + " wins!")
        return True
    if board[2] == c and board[4] == c and board[6] == c:
        #print(c + " wins!")
        return True

    #no wins game tie
    counter = 0
    for i in range(9):
        if board[i] == " ":
            # no tie found ---> game countinues
            return False
        else:
            counter += 1

    if counter == 9:
        #print("Tie Game!")
        return True

class boardNode:
    def __init__(self):
        self.boardState = ()
        self.children = []
        self.winner = ""

    def numChildren(self):
        return len(self.availableMoves())

    def availableMoves(self):
        moves = set()
        for i in range(9):
            if self.boardState[i] == " ":
                moves.add(i)
        return moves

counter = 0 
def createNode(currentBoard, posToFill, c):
    global counter
    newNode = boardNode()
    board = list(currentBoard)
    counter +=1
    if posToFill != None:
        board[int(str(posToFill))] = c
    newNode.boardState = tuple(board)
    if checkForWin(tuple(board), c) == False:
        newNode.winner = None
        if c == "X":
            for pos in newNode.availableMoves():
                newNode.children.append(createNode(newNode.boardState, pos, "O"))
        else:
            for pos in newNode.availableMoves():
                newNode.children.append(createNode(newNode.boardState, pos, "X"))
    else: 
        newNode.winner = c
    if newNode.boardState not in boardCases:
        boardCases.add(newNode.boardState)
    return newNode


def find(node, boardToSearch):
    if list(node.boardState) == list(boardToSearch):
        return node
    else:
        for child in node.children:
            return find(child, boardToSearch)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is my output for my current case:

```
$ python ticTacToe.py

None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 115, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 11, in main
    for child in nextMoves.children:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'children'
```

Comment: `find(child, boardToSearch)` should be `return find(child, boardToSearch)`.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I added that, but i'm still getting the same error

Comment: Hmm, it's actually more complicated than that I guess. You want to return a value only if it's not None, otherwise, you continue with the loop through children. But you really need to step through and debug your code to see what's going on.